# CasperJS returns base64 string as image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, screen-scraping, casperjs

I'm crawling a website using CasperJS and I have an interesting problem.

In Caspers's evaluate function, I want to extract src attribute from image `<img>` element. Here is code that will be executed in my `evaluate` function:

```
function crawl(){
    var product = {};
    try{
        product.title = jQuery('#title').html();//Get title
        product.price = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerHTML;//Get price

        var imageSrc = jQuery("#next").attr("src")
        product.image =imageSrc;
        }
    catch(e){
    }
    return JSON.stringify(product);
}
```

Here is how evaluate function is handled in Casper:

```
casper.then(function(){
        scrappedProductInfo = this.evaluate(crawl);//Get info
        console.log("Page crawled");
        utils.dump(scrappedProductInfo);
    });
```

When I execute my CasperJS script, from `evalute()` function in image attribute of returned object instead of image link I get base64 representation of the image:

```
\ndata:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABQODxIPDRQSEBIXFRQYHjIhHhwcHj0sLiQySUBMS0dARkVQWnNiUFVtVkVGZIhlbXd7gYKBTmCNl4x9lnN+gXz/2wBDARUXFx4aHjshITt8U0ZTfHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHz/wAARCAEKAKkDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAGwABAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIFAQQGAwf/xAA+EAACAgEBBAUICAQHAQAAAAABAgADEQQFEhMhFDFBVHEGM1FSkZOxwRUiMmGBkqHRI0Jy8CQ1RGKi4fFz/8QAFwEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECA//EACARAQEBAQACAgIDAAAAAAAAAAABEQIS.....
```

When I open the same page in Chrome and when I execute `crawl` function in Chrome console, I get src as link and not as base64 string. When I right-click on element and inspect it, i can clearly see URL and not base64 encoded string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That would mean that the page actually has an inlined image through data-URI. Perhaps you've selected the wrong image. Have you printed the source code to see if this is the case? Perhaps you would need to set a user agent string that resembles that of a desktop browser.

Comment: Thx for commenting. So after analyzing a bit more I realized that data-URI is there when the website is initially loaded, but data-URI is at one moment changed with concrete URL, pointing to the image with much better quality.

Comment: Do you have some suggestion how to handle this? I need URL and not data-URI

Comment: You probably have to wait a bit such as `casper.waitForSelector("img[src^='http']")`. Change the selector according to your needs